# Recursive Functions return value

Tags: c, recursion, return-type

I don't seem to understand the logic behind this particular code. I don't understand why the answer is 18. You can check for the answer in a compiler as well. Anyone wh understands the logic please let me know.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int GuessMe(int,int);
main() {
    printf("%d", GuessMe(8,2));
}

int GuessMe(int x, int y) {
    if ( y >  x)
        return x
    else
        return GuessMe(x-2, y+2) + x;
}
```

Comment: Show code, not links

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Comment: for this - neither show an image nor show code. Use a debugger, set a breakpoint, inspect the variables and take notes. 18 is correct. this is no real question for SO - see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Explain what you've tried. Ask specific questions about any points of confusion, not just a general "explain this code".

Comment: This is a very simple recursive function where it adds `8 + 6 + 4` where `4` is the `return x` since `y` is `6` and larger than `4`. I don't quite understand what you don't understand about it. Are you unsure if `(8 + 6 + 4) == 18` or do you not understand how function calls work?

Comment: @Sylwester recursion is often not intuitive for beginners

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. I eventually figured out the answer is 18, but I can't figured out why x and y are added in GuessMe(x-2,y+2)

Answer (score 1):

Initially, `GuessMe` is passed `x=8,y=2`:

```
x | y | y > x ? | initial return value |  final return value
8 | 2 |    NO   |  GuessMe(6, 4) + 8   |     18
6 | 4 |    NO   |  GuessMe(4, 6) + 6   |     10
4 | 6 |   YES   |         4            |      4
```

Read down the `initial return value` column and then read back up the final `return value column` once you hit an `initial return value` that isn't recursive.